# wordpress notification section wp_post all data face but how to image is not display|How to display image wp_post image

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image

[See Issue Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzbfX.png)

```
function demo1(){
    $args = array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false
    );

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args );
    $post_types['post'] = ''; // default = 'and'
```

here is my code facing issue **wp_post** guide Image not facing how to display image give me some idea

```
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    
        echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
        for ($x=0;   $x<=0; $x++){
    
           $args = array( 'numberposts' => $x, 'post_type' => $post_type); // replace n with the number of posts
           $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    
           foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
               ?>
               <div style="border: 1px solid; text-decoration: none; padding:10px 0px 10px 20px; ">
                   <?php 
                   echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'" >'."<h3 style='text-decoration: none;color:#000000'>" .$recent["post_title"] . "</h3>". '</a>';
                   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['post_title'] ).'" height="200" width="200"/>'.'<br>';
                   // echo '<img src='. get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'>'.$recent["guid"].'</br>';
                   echo '<i href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'" >' .$recent["post_modified"] . '</i></br>';
                   ?>
               </div>
               <?php    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi.  Your question is unclear.  Could you please explain better what you're trying to do?

Comment: WordPress, Wp_Post Object Image Are Store Right But How To Access His Image Explain Me Details